# How to suppress text insertion on copy in web browsers?

Tags: safari

This website inserts text when you copy and paste: http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/blogs/ninerinsider/index . Is there any way to suppress that? I am using Safari 4.

EDIT: Here is another site that does it: www.nationalpost.com/story.html?id=2155193 . It's really annoying.

Comment: Whoa! I've never seen a website do that before - it's kind of neat!

Comment: Very interesting. Doesn't seem to happen in Firefox 3.5.4 though.

Comment: Can't see it either in FF or IE8.

Comment: I just tried on Opera10 and i didnt see any extra text in the copy paste

Comment: Wow that's scary, works in Chrome and IE8 though fails randomly/initially in IE - the page does some slight loading whenever I hit ctrl+c or context menu copy... and it does insert the link in the clipboard...

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you could install the extension NoScript.  I'm sure you could also create a Greasemonkey script to block their script, but I have no experience with that.